# Can you override an "onscroll" listener by using another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a problem where I want to override the global onscroll event listener with one specifically assigned to an element.

Here is an example.

```js
$("a").on('click', function(){
  console.log('Clicked');
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:50}, 1000);
  var count = 0;
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if(count < 5)
    {
      console.log('Scrolling via link...'); 
    }
    count++;
  });
});

var globalCount = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if(globalCount < 5)
  {
    console.log('Scrolling...');
  }
  globalCount++;
});
```

```css
body{min-height:2000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

How do I **prevent** the *console.log('Scrolling...')* from running?

Comment: jQuery on() appends events, not overrides them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `event.stopPropagation()`

```js
$("a").on('click', function(){
  console.log('Clicked');
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:50}, 1000);
  var count = 0;
  $(window).on('scroll', function(event){
    if(count < 5)
    {
      console.log('Scrolling via link...'); 
    }
    count++;
    //stop propagation stops the bubbling of the event down to further event handlers.
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});

var globalCount = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if(globalCount < 5)
  {
    console.log('Scrolling...');
  }
  globalCount++;
});
```

```css
body{min-height:2000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand exactly what you're trying to do... but, you can unregister the scroll event handler that you attach at the bottom inside the click event handler, just before you attach your new one, by doing `$(window).off('scroll')`

```js
$("a").on('click', function(){
  console.log('Clicked');
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:50}, 1000, attachGlobalListener);
  var count = 0;
  $(window).off('scroll'); //This removes the "global" event handler specified at the bottom of this snippet
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if(count < 5)
    {
      console.log('Scrolling via link...'); 
    }
    count++;
  });
});

function attachGlobalListener(){
    var globalCount = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event){
      if(globalCount < 5)
      {
        console.log('Scrolling...');
      }
      globalCount++;
    });
}
//attach the listener to begin with
attachGlobalListener();
```

```css
body{min-height:2000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazing.  Thank you!

On another note, can the global listener be reattached right after the link-based listener is finished?

Comment: Yeah you could re-attach the global listener as a 3rd parameter in the `.animate` method which would mean it runs when the animation has finished. eg something like `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:50}, 1000, reattachScrollListener);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag to check if you need to handle global scroll event. BTW, don't forget to unbind nested scroll event once animation done. Here is an example:

```js
$("a").on('click', function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
  globalScroll = false;
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: 50
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(window).off('scroll.clicked');
    globalScroll = true;
  });
  var count = 0;
  $(window).on('scroll.clicked', function() {
    if (count < 5) {
      console.log('Scrolling via link...');
    }
    count++;
  });
});

var globalCount = 0,
  globalScroll = true;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (!globalScroll) return;
  if (globalCount < 5) {
    console.log('Scrolling...');
  }
  globalCount++;
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```